# "Why are American bathtubs so low down?" Why "low down" whereas simply "low" would suffice?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from a british native speaker's youtube video who lives in US [why bathtubs are low down in USA](https://youtu.be/ESC7pHiQeXs)

**Why are American bathtubs so low down?**

Why does he say **"low down"**? Wouldn't the word **"low"** simply mean the same?

Comment: We often add unnecessary additional prepositions. Sometimes specifically to add emphasis, sometimes for no particular reason apart from habit. So something might be *high **up** in the air* or *deep **down** in the ground*. And although we can just [*fill an application form,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fill+the+application+form%22) we usually either *fill it **out*** or *fill it **in***. (Prepositions are two a penny in English! :)

Comment: He _doesn't_ repeat 'are'.

Comment: I'm not watching a video on bathrooms. Does it mean that the sides are low (the bath is shallow), or the tub is set low in the floor? "Low down" to me suggests the latter.

Comment: Yes, it mentions that, unlike in UK, the tubs in USA are set low in the floor(not the sides being low). He says the ones in the UK are not level with the ground of bathroom, and they stand elevated so the water pipes could fit under the tub.